# How to browse NSDocumentDirectory on iPhone as a user

Tags: iphone, xcode

My app exports a file that I want the user to access on the Directory:

/Users/aris/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/{deviceid}/data/Containers/Data/Application/{appid}/Documents.

I can see the file on my Mac but I can't find it anywhere on the iPhone simulator.